# Touch on ImageView to another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have 2 `ViewControllers` and I create one `UIImageView` to show like Splash Screen on IPhone. I write it in `TestAppDelegate.m` :

====================

```
splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

splashScreen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

[self.window addSubview:splashScreen];

 sleep(6);

[splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
```

====================

My question is,

if I touch on this `imageview` I will go to 2nd `ViewController`.

else after time sleep, automatically to 1st `ViewController`.

So, it's possible to do that ?

Comment: How about your image being a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in appDelegate.h file.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Now

```
splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
splashScreen.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
splashScreen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[splashScreen addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];

[self.window addSubview:splashScreen];

sleep(6);
[splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
//add ViewController1 here
ViewController1 *objViewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:objViewController1.view];
```

Now handler will be called when tapped on splash screen

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
   // Do Your thing. 
   if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
   {
     [splashScreen removeFromSuperview]; //edited here
     ViewController2 *objViewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:objViewController2.view];
   }
}
```

Comment: The FirstViewController works but SecondViewController not work. I don't know why.

Comment: It not called method handTap, I also log it.

Comment: tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self; added this in answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.In AppDelegate keep `NSTimer`.

In the selector of timer write code to push to the 1st view controller.

And put a `Touch Recognizer` on the imageview and on the touch event write code to push to the 2nd View Controller.